# How can I have bigger fontsize than \fontsize{60}{70}?

Tags: fontsize, documentclass-writing

I am writing my thesis and the font size of the chapter title is defined in the class of the document. Somehow I cannot make bigger than `\fontsize{60}{70}`. Even if I write `\fontsize{3000}{70}` I cannot observe any difference. 
Is there a way to change it?

Thanks

My code (in the class file):

```
% Numbered chapter heading style:
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  {\singlespacing
    \parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont

    \vspace*{5mm}%  
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \fontsize{120}{60} \selectfont \scshape \bf \textsc \space \thechapter         % Chapter followed by number
    \par\nobreak
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vspace{20mm}%  
    \huge \scshape \bf #1\par                                                            % chapter title
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}                                                                                  %horizontontal line                     
    \nobreak
   \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean `60/70` seriously? That's really large! You should see a lot of warnings in your `.log` file

Comment: Do you really have `\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}` in the middle of your chapter heading definition? How can that not give multiple errors?

Comment: It depends on whether your font admits the specified size. Have a look at `lmodern` with some large sizes: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\Enlarge[2]{{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont test}}
\begin{document}

\Enlarge{60}{72}
\Enlarge{120}{144}\par
\Enlarge{500}{600}

\end{document}`

Comment: The `\usepackage` lines have to be at the top level so they execute before the document starts. They can not be in the definition of `\chapter`.

Comment: `\scshape \bf` is the same as `\bf` did you intend `\scshape \bfseries` which specifies bold caps and small caps (which is not available in all font families)?

Comment: My document class is {thesis} but I am modifying the class document so the file starts with:% First identify the class:

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{report} and finish with % end of file:
\endinput

Comment: the comment above doesn't really seem to add any extra information. The answer given shows how to have fonts bigger than 60pt, It is hard to guess the intention of the `\@makechapterhead` definition in the question but the errors it generates are basically unrelated to the question in the title.

Comment: If you are using KOMA script, this will break all kinds of functionality.... (The KOMA classes define `\@makechapterhead` so this is a guess about what `thesis` might be doing.)

Comment: @cfr most classes with a chapter command define this,eg `report` and `book`

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

one {\fontsize{5cm}{6cm}\selectfont two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \usepackage{lmodern} is what is needed, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you select a font size using `\fontsize` and then use a regular font size command such as `\huge`, you will get back to the ordinarily `huge` size. This probably isn't an issue since I can't imagine you are trying to make the chapter title this big as well, but since your question is difficult to figure out, maybe this might be useful.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

  \fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont enormous

  \huge merely huge

\end{document}
```

[image: enormous vs. merely huge]

Note that `\bf` is deprecated and undoes `\scshape`, as pointed out in comments. `\scshape\bfseries` will switch to bold small-caps if they are available (unusual).

Note that `\textsc{}` is not a font switch but expects an argument.

So, if you just say `\textsc` without curly brackets, the next token will be small-caps - typically a single letter. Compare:

```
  \textsc abc

  \textsc{abc}

  {\scshape abc}
```

[image: font shape commands]